# Libgdx Version Nightly Build or Release Build? Action Package Different

Tags: action, libgdx, versions, nightly-build

I have been working with Libgdx for some time now (part time only). Just recently I had to use `Actions` in my game. I found out some tutorials/examples online and when I tried to implement them in my project, some functions were not recognized by the compiler.

I particularly ran into problem with `SequenceAction` i-e the (Overridden) constructors weren't there for my current libgdx. So I went online to see this [doc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/) and there they were, all constructors. Also, refer to this screen shot:

[image]

So, I simply downloaded the latest version. i-e libgdx-0.9.8 from [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/downloads/detail?name=libgdx-0.9.8.zip) **But** when I opened the docs locally, I couldn't see those constructors again...

Here's a screenshot of my PC browsing that docs.

[image]

As u can see, there are no constructors which are there, just one default Constructor.

Next, I downloaded the libgdx-nightly-latest version from [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/) (as the online api also shows nighly docs) and I found those constructors there. 
Same is the case with `ParallelAction` class

Now coming to my questions:

1. How is the latest release build usually different as compared to nightly builds?
2. Is this problem valid or am i just too sleepy to miss something here?
3. Which one should I use in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Libgdx nightly builds have a lot of API changes accumulated in them (its been a while since the 0.9.8 release).  Mario & Co. try to document any such API changes in blog posts, so if you're following the nightly builds, you'll definitely want to keep up with [the blog](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/).  The ["CHANGES" file](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/CHANGES) in the nightly distribution also has notes on what has changed (but I think this may not have some early changes in it).

Its hard to know what version a 3rd party blog or article is talking about if they don't explicitly list the version.  You can sometimes go by the date on the article, though.

Anyway, I think its safe to use either the "stable" build or the nightlies.  There are non-trivial API changes when switching between the two versions, so you'll want to stick with one for a while, but these changes are almost always a good idea for all involved.  (The Libgdx maintainers don't take API changes lightly, but they don't rule them out either, yet -- presumably that will change with version 1.0.0.).

Comment: I'm just wondering why are there a lot of changes in these two files. and why on many blogs I'm finding stuff which is in nightly. Does this mean that nightly is better?

Comment: All work done since libgdx 0.9.8 shows up in the "nightly" builds, which is about 8 months of work at this point.  So, there are quite a few changes spread through-out.  Ideally, they're all improvements.  I doubt it will help, but there is always the changelog to describe what has changed: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commits/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/SequenceAction.java

Comment: So in the end, what would u recommend me to use? nightly?

Comment: Yeah, nightly is fine.

Comment: Ok, then I shall be using that for some time. Thanks!